# Report is working fine but calling stored procedure in Management Studio not working

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which uses a stored procedure which takes 2 parameters and then show the results.

```
exec TestingCode @startdate, #endate
```

When I run the report from Report Server, it runs smoothly without any error message. Now when I run the stored procedure with 2 parameters in SQL Server Management Studio like this

```
exec TestingCode '2012-01-01' , '2012-03-01'
```

then I get conversion error message.

I know how to fix the error but why running from reporting server passing the parameter from reports not causing the report to fail but if I execute the stored procedure from Management Studio it fails...

Thanks

Ally

Answer (score 1):

There are many string-based date formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

So in your case, try this call:

```
exec TestingCode '20120101', '20120301'
```

Does that work?

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.